# Use Google API JSON to convert rss to JSONP

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, rss, google-api

I'm trying to incorporate some rss feeds into a JQM page. However, I've not found any suitable method to do this. So since I have JSON feeds elsewhere in the app, I figured I'd convert the rss feeds into JSON.

Ive tried several tools such as RSSMix and Yahoo Pipes but these all seem to chuck out some data that isn't in double quotes. So this throws the getJSON call and so isn't usable.

Now I'm trying googleapis to do the conversion and face another issue. Below is the call I make to google to convert the rss to JSON:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?hl=ja&output=json-in-script&q=http://www.avbuyer.com/articles/articles.asp&v=1.0&num=100&callback=listEntries
```

This is the JQ i call to try and display the resultant feed:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(qryString,
    function(data){

        //build listview
        $.each(data.entries, function(i,item){
            li+='<li><a href="" onclick="OnSubmit(\'' + item.link.trim() + '\')" data-transition="slidedown"><span style="font-size:0.75em;">' + item.title.trim() + '</span><br/><span style="font-size:0.65em;">' + item.Description.trim() + '</span></a></li>';
        });
            $("#results-list").append('<li class="center border-bottom" data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Aircraft Found: ' + data.resultCount + '</li>');//add result count to top
            $("#results-list").append(li);
            $("#results-list").append('<li class="center border-top" data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Aircraft Found: ' + data.resultCount + '</li>');//add result count to bottom
            $("#results-list").listview("refresh");
        });
```

Firebug console gives me the following error when I run the page:

```
TypeError: obj is undefined
length = obj.length,
```

Note, Ive tried both 'data.entries' and 'data.items' in the $.each loop.

Comment: Objects has no `.length` only arrays.

Comment: @Omar Any idea what I need to change? I've used getJSON elsewhere on my site to grab JSONP data from my server, without problem. Evidently this JSON is different in some manner. Any suggestions/pointers would be appreciated as always.

Comment: Can you post sample of retrieved data?

Comment: @Omar The link in my OP is a live url.

Comment: @Omar ok I've just made some changes and now I get no errors on in Firebug/console, but I'm not getting anything shown in the listview.

Comment: @Omar So I've got no errors in Firebug, but the .fail part of the getJSON is being called. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the feed data it seems its got a different hierarchy than on other JSON feeds. I need to get all the "entries" however these are stacked inside "feed" which is a child of "responseData". I can't work out how to access "entries" in my getJSON.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50982/discussion-between-omar-and-phill-healey)

Comment: have you checked the chat?

Comment: Just replied mate. ;-)